# Allow a group of users to create and write to files in a given directory

Tags: users, user-management, groups

I want to have different users including www-data to work together under a specific path. including updating each others files.

I made a new group webimage

```
addgroup webimage
```

and

```
adduser user1 webimage
adduser user2 webimage
adduser www-data webimage
```

I changed the permissions of the imagedir

```
chown -R www-data:webimage image/
```

and `user1` can write but the file has permisions

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1       user1
```

and no one can update the file but this user. How can I get this to work in a secure manner. Outside of this directory of course each users file is private as usual.

Comment: Having multiple devs work on the same machine is… very weird. What exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: @Alexander multiple person should be able to update images wich are also manipulated (scaled or cropped) by the webserver. I don't think it's weird (persons are not developers - in case you think on vcs)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `setgid` bit for that:

```
sudo chmod g+s image/
```

This will cause any file created in that directory to be owned by the same group as the directory. Thus, if `image` is owned by group `webimage`, any file created there will be owned by the group `webimage`. If also read and write permissions are set for the group, all members of the group will be able to update the file.

Comment: This is pure gold, thanks